# Postgres Update with Window Query Deadlocks

Tags: sql, postgresql, deadlock

I'm running the following two commands in a transaction.

```
UPDATE ordered_set SET
  -- other fields omitted
  rank = $7 - 0.5
WHERE ordered_set_id = $1

UPDATE ordered_set b SET
  rank = t.rank
FROM (
  SELECT ordered_set_id, row_number() OVER(ORDER BY rank) AS rank
  FROM ordered_set
  WHERE ordered_set_parent_id = $1
) t
WHERE b.ordered_set_id = t.ordered_set_id;
```

This trick ensures that if the `rank` field is updated, it updates it to the correct value relative to its siblings, then normalizes all ranks which would be queried together.

This query reliably deadlocks when several transactions are run concurrently. Is there either

- a better method to ensure that ranks are normalized after such an update (this normalization process is also run in the transaction when a set item is deleted), or
- a way to lock the rows in this update to prevent such a deadlock?

Comment: I would have thought a SELECT FOR UPDATE would have done the job. Is it not?